# How to deactivate keyboard buffer in Windows?

Tags: python, keyboard, vpython

I'm trying to program something using vPython.
It's kind of a game, but controls won't work properly.

```
while True:
    "verarbeitet Maus/Tastatureingaben"        
    if scene.kb:                        # wenn Aktion auf der Tastatur...
        druck=scene.kb.getkey()         # ...Tastendruck speichern!
        # ----Aktionen bei bestimmten Tasten---- #
        if druck == "w":            # vor
            self.bewegen(self.axis)
        elif druck == "s":          # zurück
            self.bewegen(-self.axis)
```

So there are two main problems:

1. Two keys can't be pressed at the same time. Only the one pressed latest is working.
2. If holding a key for about 5 seconds the action will take much longer (I think that's because `MS Windows` takes a small break after each 'hit').

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try running your script with -u option:

```
python -u myscript.py
```

You can find documentation on this option [here](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)

As per document:

```
Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, 
also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary mode.
```

Comment: hmmm, can I also start this from the script itself?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about vPython. Does scene.kb return true while keys are pressed? if so, you could do something like this:

```
keys = []
while scene.kb:
    keys.append(scene.kb.getkey())

if "w" in keys and "s" in keys:
    // do something
```